# Unable to mount Samsung Android Device with Android Studio on Ubuntu 14.04 OS

Tags: android, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, samsung-mobile

I have been using Android Studio with Ubuntu 14.04. But I get strange behaviour when I try to connect my Samsung S5 with Android Studio on my computer.

Sometimes it works. But often it fails to do so.

I get multiple File windows popping up showing Android phone's files; sometimes even new file windows continuously pop ups. Android Studio's Device Chooser displays "Nothing to show"

This is what error I often get and it repeats after every few seconds.

1. Unable to mount Samsung Android
2. Unable to open MTP device '[USB: 001, 013]'

This is how I have tried to resolve the issue but failed to do so.

1. I've already installed adk, but it has had no success.
2. I've already installed mtpfs, but it has had no success.
3. I've already installed mtp-tools mtpfs, but it has had no success.

Any suggestions on how I can connect my phone with Android studio? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem by using a different USB lead between my phone and my computer. Although the lead that came with the phone is able to charge the phone battery, it seems to only intermittently be able to transfer data. Perhaps there is loose connection. The replacement lead works perfectly.